# ios json serialization NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 error

Tags: ios, iphone, json

Hi I am working on json serialization on search key word if we didn't found search key then it will return empty like below

> {"jobs":[]}

but I am getting error while parsing below is my code snippet

```
__block BOOL userGetJobDataIsReceived = NO;
NSURL *url;
NSData *postData;
 defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 postData =[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"user_id=%ld&search=%@",(long)userID,self.textField.text]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://getjoblocation.com/webservices/searchjobs.php?"];

NSLog(@"Search URL => %@%@",url,postData);
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration]];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *requestError) {
                        NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

                        if (requestError) {
                            NSLog(@"Request error occurred: %@", requestError);
                        }

                        //if communication was successful
                        if ([HTTPResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [HTTPResponse statusCode] < 300) {
                            NSLog(@"status code ::::%ld",(long)[HTTPResponse statusCode]);

                            NSInteger success = 1;
                            NSError *serializeError = nil;
                            NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                                      JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                      options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                      error:&serializeError];
                            success = [jsonData[@"ERROR"] integerValue];
                            if (serializeError) {
                                NSLog(@"JSON serialize error occurred: %@", serializeError);
                            }

                            if (success==0) {

                                userGetJobDataIsReceived = YES;
                                //do stuff with jsonData dictionary here

                                NSLog(@"Search Response: %@ ",jsonData);

                                if([userTypeForGetJOb isEqualToString:@"Worker"]) {

                                    if ((unsigned long)[jobsDetailArray count]==0) {
                                        //if not job
                                        avijitIndexNumberItem=0;
                                        [self.view addSubview:self.SearchContainerView];

                                        // self.searchViewLabel.text=NSLocalizedString(@"No_Job_Found_Tap_pic_LocStr", @"No jobs found please tap profile picture to search again");
                                        self.searchViewLabel.text=NSLocalizedString(@"No_Job_Found_Tap_pic_LocStr", @"Job approval are reviewed by employee, when he accept we will update you.");

                                    }else{
                                        NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

                                        [self.SearchContainerView removeFromSuperview];
                                        //cution
                                        avijitIndexNumberItem=0;
                                        [self indexChangedPleaseChangeStuff:0];

                                    }
                                }
```

now I am getting repose code 200 and response is null and error is

> NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 error  "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.)

where I miss please any body help me

Comment: Can you post the son response text here?

Comment: sorry i didn't get you you mean json responce then it is null

Comment: Check what data is getting, From the error it seems that is not valid son, eve though its 200 response code,

Comment: For getting the response in the console put a breakpoint in completion handler and enter following line in debugger area
[[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding:4];

Comment: I tried using your we service but its getting You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
        order by jobs.datetime desc' at line 22

Comment: First of all, make sure your inputs are correct, also Something is wrong in the web service, that is not handling error input cases properly, thats why its returning this error message with 200 response code

Comment: Hi  Johnykutty if you don't mine can you please check it now i am getting json responce like 00
2015-10-30 16:04:33.938 Jobibon[21342:193308] Search Response: {
    Message = "UserId not define";
    status = 0;
} 
because i am unable to send the userid corrently but i don't know where i miss

Comment: now the son is parsing correctly I think, issue is "UserId not define". may be ur user id is not valid.  make sure you are sending  user_id properly.

Comment: Thankyou Johnykutty you saved my time thankyou verymuch

Comment: actually what was the issue?

Comment: the issue is i am unable to get the userId now it is working fine for me

Answer (score -1):

Change `NSData *postData;` to `NSMutableData *postData;`

Comment: when i am changing it to mutable then it is showing warning like incompatable pointer type any sol